# phpStorm file changes

Tags: git, laravel, phpstorm

I am working in Laravel5 (Vagrant/Homestead/Git).

I got a problem : Each time, I checkout to a another branch, phpStorm is not reflecting the changes in the files from the other branch.
While I can see it from Finder or another software (Coda).

I am forced to right-click and "Synchronize 'folder'" and it is becoming annoying.

Anyone solved this problem ?

Comment: I think that's just a quirk of PHPStorm - synchronizing the folder seems to the only way to tell it to update.

Comment: Thank you anyway @Coderrrr ! Really not pleasing. :(

Comment: Are you checkout from phpstorm or outside? I think storm trigger a refresh event if you doing it from the app, but doesn't know it changed if you doing it ouside. Collapse the root folder and open up again makes a refresh, but its also not so pleasant. I have this refresh problem with generated files outside from storm... :(

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if **Synchronize files on frame activation** is checked

[image]

You can also manually Synchronize files wih <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> on mac (Files > Synchronize).

Comment: I have the same settings as you show.. Maybe it is a RAM (4Go) problem ?